# Why do these C++ lambdas copy the string and seg fault?

Tags: c++, lambda

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Foo
{
public:
    const std::string& GetData() { return m_data; }
    std::string m_data = "foo data";
};

std::string s_data = "hello";
const std::string& GetData() { return s_data; }

int main()
{
    // Trial #1 - Seg faults.  String copied.
    //std::function<const std::string&()> getter1 = [] { return GetData(); };
    //std::cout << "data = " << getter1() << std::endl;

    // Trial #2 - Seg faults.  String copied.
    //auto* foo = new Foo();
    //std::function<const std::string&()> getter2 = [foo] { return foo->GetData(); };
    //std::cout << "data = " << getter2() << std::endl;
    //delete foo;

    // Trial #3 - Works
    auto getter3 = [] { return GetData(); };
    std::cout << "data = " << getter3() << std::endl;

    // Trial #4 - Works
    auto* foo2 = new Foo();
    auto getter4 = [foo2] { return foo2->GetData(); };
    std::cout << "data = " << getter4() << std::endl;
    delete foo2;

    return 0;
}
```

In trials 1 & 2, execution of the lambda makes a copy of the string data rather than just passing along the const string& it gets from the GetData() function it called.  The copy destructs, presumably before the reference to it is used - causing the seg fault.  But, I don't understand why a copy was made at all.

Trials 3 & 4 work.  I'm guessing getter3 and getter4 are std::functionstd::string() such that a string copy is returned rather than a reference.

Comment: *"I don't understand why a copy was made at all...."* Because `std::function` makes a copy.

Comment: @user12002570 Can you elaborate?  I'm asking why a new string object is made instead of just passing along the reference.  Is there something that requires this behavior?  It seems non-inutitive to me.

Comment: Wrong duplicates. Reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[] { return GetData(); }` is `[]() -> auto { return GetData(); }` and `auto` is deduced to `std::string`. Your code is
equivalent to

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string s_data = "hello";
const std::string& GetData() {
  return s_data;
}

const std::string lambda() {
  return GetData();
}

const std::string& getter1() {
  return lambda();  // warning: returning reference to local temporary object [-Wreturn-stack-address]
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "data = " << getter1() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The possible fix:

```
[]() -> auto& { return GetData(); }
```

https://godbolt.org/z/nrz8hv8Yr

Comment: Thank you!  I was re-reading about std::function and lambdas returning referneces without trailing-return-type.  I was not familiar with that last term and failed to understand the importance.